# Replace nested property for an interview

Tags: javascript, interview-questions

During an interview I was given this interesting JavaScript task:

> Given the code:
>
> ```
> const testStr = "bar.baz.foo:111222",
>       testObj = {
>         bar: {
>           baz: {
>             foo: 333444,
>             foo2: 674654
>           },
>           boo: {
>             faa: 11
>           }
>         },
>         fee: 333
>       };
>
> function replaceInObj(obj, str) {
>   // your code
> }
> ```
>
> write the implementation of the `replaceInObj` function

I was not allowed to use a 3rd-party library. I kinda solved the task, but I'm not satisfied with my solution and I'm struggling with my complex implementation. At the same time I cannot find another solution by myself.

### My implementation of the `replaceInObj` function

```js
const testStr = 'bar.baz.foo:111222';
const testObj = {
  bar: {
    baz: {
      foo: 333444,
      foo2: 674654,
    },
    boo: {
      faa: 11,
    },
  },
  fee: 333,
};

console.log('[before] testObj.bar.baz =', testObj.bar.baz);

// run
replaceInObj(testObj, testStr);

console.log('[after] testObj.bar.baz =', testObj.bar.baz);

function replaceInObj(obj, str) {
  const [path, valueToChange] = str.split(':');

  path.split('.').reduce((acc, prop, index, arr) => {
    const isLastProp = arr.length === index + 1;
    if (isLastProp) {
      acc[prop] = valueToChange;
    }

    return acc[prop];
  }, obj);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of your solutions handles the type of the replacement correctly. For instance `"bar.baz.foo:111222"` replaces `foo:333444` with `foo:"111222"` where I would expect it to result in `foo:111222`.

Further they can handle if the replacement is an array, but not if it is an object due to the use of `split(':')`. You should use `str.indexOf(':')` together with `str.substr()` instead:

```
function replaceInObj(obj, str) {
  let splitIndex = str.indexOf(':');
  let [path, replacement] = [str.substr(0, splitIndex), str.substr(splitIndex + 1)];
  let sections = path.split('.');
  let sub = obj;
  for (var i = 0; i < sections.length - 1; i++) {
    sub = sub[sections[i]];
  }

  sub[sections[i]] = JSON.parse(replacement);
  return obj;
}
```

Here `JSON.parse()` is used to interpret the value to the correct type. I don't know if the `JSON` api is considered as "third-party" in this context.

---

There is a more "quick and dirty" approach using `eval`:

```
function replaceInObj(obj, str) {
  let splitIndex = str.indexOf(':');
  let [path, replacement] = [str.substr(0, splitIndex), str.substr(splitIndex + 1)];
  eval("obj." + path + "=" + replacement);
  return obj;
}
```

---

Some test cases:

```js
  let testObj = {
    bar: {
      baz: {
        foo: 333444,
        foo2: 674654
      },
      boo: {
        faa: 11
      }
    },
    fee: 333
  };

    let replacements = [
      "bar.baz.foo:111222",
      "bar.baz.foo:\"05-31-2020\"",
      "bar.baz.foo:false",
      "bar.baz.foo:\"abcdefg\"",
      "bar.baz.foo:[111222, 21341234, 234243]",
      "bar.baz.foo:{ \"aaa\": 1234, \"bbb\": \"hello world\" }"
    ];

    for (let replacement of replacements) {
      let result = replaceInObj(testObj, replacement);
      console.log(result.bar.baz.foo);
    }


function replaceInObj(obj, str) {
  let splitIndex = str.indexOf(':');
  let [path, replacement] = [str.substr(0, splitIndex), str.substr(splitIndex + 1)];
  eval("obj." + path + "=" + replacement);
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Liked your solution and explanation! How incredibly you handled those edge-cases with possibility to pass any JSON-valid string

Comment: Great work! 

Answer (score 0):

I think I found solution much cleaner and simpler to understand:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/240907/227075

### That solution adjusted to my task

```js
const testStr = 'bar.baz.foo:111222';
const testObj = {
  bar: {
    baz: {
      foo: '333444',
    },
  },
};

console.log('[before] testObj.bar.baz =', testObj.bar.baz);

// run
replaceInObj(testObj, testStr);

console.log('[after] testObj.bar.baz =', testObj.bar.baz);

function replaceInObj(obj, str) {
  const [path, valueToChange] = str.split(':');
  const properties = path.split('.');
  const lastProperty = properties.pop();
  const lastObject = properties.reduce((a, prop) => a[prop], obj);
  lastObject[lastProperty] = valueToChange;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why it is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process.